# Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject Android

Tags: c#, android, web-services

I'm trying to upload image using android to C# web service

Web service takes these parameters:

```
byte[] data, string strFileName
```

but everytime i run the app! it gave me this error:

```
Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is the code:

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://192.168.1.100:8080/ScanFiles.asmx?op=vFileUpload");
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);

            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            entity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fnameglob));
            entity.addPart("data", new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg", fnameglob)); 

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            response.getEntity().getContent(), "iso-8859-1"));

            String sResponse = reader.readLine();
            return sResponse;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }

        // (null);
    }
```

Any suggestions? Any help highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my case by using the following code:

```
    protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bos);

            byte[] byte_arr = bos.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", image_str));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strFileName",
                    fnameglob));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://192.168.1.100:1234/ScanFiles.asmx/vFileUpload");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                                .getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                return sResponse;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("HTTP", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            } finally {

            }
        } finally {

        }
        return "done";

        // (null);
    }
```

and this is the web service code

```
  [WebMethod]
    public void vFileUpload(string data, string strFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = data.Length.ToString();
            string sDestinationScannedFiles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationScannedFiles"].ToString();
            //string filePath = Server.MapPath(sDestinationScannedFiles +  strFileName);
            string filePath = sDestinationScannedFiles + strFileName;

            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, Convert.FromBase64String(data));
        }
```

if you want to find the base64 class you may find it [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-commons/chemistry-opencmis-commons-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/impl/Base64.java)

Thanks.